# Xcode Error When Building

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk, xcode3.2

Whenever I compile something in Xcode, I get 3 errors. One is under "Checking dependencies" and says "Unable to create directory /var/folders/zZ/string of letters/more directories/more letters." What is wrong with Xcode/my computer? I switched to the Xcode 4 preview and that works fine, but is not stable. Yes, I have tried restarting. This has been going on for weeks. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can we have the error messages please?

Comment: When I click build and click on the number at the bottom (in this case, there are 3 errors), the first one says unable to create directory. The other 2 are under Precompile MyApp_Prefix.pch. One says error, couldn't create directory then the second says Can't create precompiled header. I will post the full error message for the first one:

Comment: error: couldn't create directory /var/folders/zZ/zZoTZWgpGbC0BHDQxYkifk+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyApp_Prefix-eqhlxgbqyuulatfiovcbfhaxgoeg: Permission denied/Users/Preston/Developer/MyApp/MyApp_Prefix.pch:1: fatal error: can't create precompiled header /var/folders/zZ/zZoTZWgpGbC0BHDQxYkifk+++TI/-Caches-/com.apple.Xcode.501/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/MyApp_Prefix-eqhlxgbqyuulatfiovcbfhaxgoeg/MyApp_Prefix.pch.gch: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, which showed up after switching to xcode 4. The error was:

error: unable to create '/build' (Permission denied)

The solution was to change '/build' to 'build' in the project configuration under Intermediate Build File Path.

In your case I would guess the pch file has a path that starts with '/'.

Comment: I fixed the problem by reinstalling my OS (without deleting my files). But at the time this question was asked, I was using Xcode 3.